# Can you have a relationship with a *category* instead of a 'channel' in channel fields?

Tags: categories, relationships, channel-fields

I want to setup a 'Pages' channel in such a way where I can include a loop from a different channel (in this case 'Listings') only showing entries for a particular category.  I'm using Structure to arrange my sitemap, so I can't use segments in the URL - plus it will only be relevant for certain pages and not others, so I need to find a way the user can select a related 'Listings' category when editing the 'Page' if appropriate which would then power a listings loop.

Can anyone advise or link to somewhere that shows how to do this?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of fieldtype add-ons which allow you to select a category. I've used [WB Category Select](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/wb-category-select) on a number of occasions with great success to do just what you're asking.

Comment: That's perfect, I was looking for an extension/plugin to do this, but didn't see any - maybe was the phrasing of my searches.  Still new to EE, so building up my repertoire of plugins!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Glad it's a good fit for you. :)